# Is it possible to monitor the progress of individual TIdFTPServer client downloads?

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I have a TIdFTPServer that has several clients connected simultaneously. I want to monitor the progress of each of the client downloads.

Anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively, no.  However, the `OnRetrieveFile` and `OnStoreFile` events allow you to provide your own `TStream` objects for transferring the raw file data, so you can write your own `TStream` descendant classes and have them override the virtual `Read()` and `Write()` methods, or use Indy's own `TIdEventStream` class, to do whatever you need.